# Regex issue - Replace floats, not int

Tags: javascript, regex

Im want to remove all but the float in this sting:

```
string = "1 south african rand is 0.11044"
```

Im doing it like this:

```
reg = /[^\d+.\d+]/g
console.log string.replace(reg, '')
```

that logs

```
10.11044
```

that is wrong, I want only the xxxx.xxxxx part. 1 is not a float so it should not be part of this?

How should I chage it?

Comment: `[^....]` matches any individual character that isn't one of the ones inside the brackets. It's not looking for sequences.

Comment: The matching bit works great, just not with the [] yes..

Comment: I've corrected my answer using a negative look-around. Tested, works correctly my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
^((?!\d+\.\d+).)*
```

See this answer for more details: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 2):

Following regex should match floats for you (for the example provided):

```
/(-?\d*\.\d+)/
```

To replace:

```
console.log (string.replace(/(-?\d*\.\d+)/, ''));
```

Comment: He was trying to match words that were not floats however, to remove them.

Comment: I provided him regex to match float numbers, that can be used to replace. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used positive look behind (?<=..) in below regular expression

```
\.\d+(?<=\d)
```

Use this regular expression and replace below value with ''. The result will be 1 23 33 3

```
1 23 33.2000 3.4445
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think his desired result is `33.2000 3.4445`. `1` and `23` should be excluded because they don't have a decimal point and fraction.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = /\d+\.\d+/g
var str = "1 south african rand is 0.11044";
var onlyFloats = str.match(reg).join(" ");
console.log(onlyFloats)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string = "1 south african rand is 0.11044"
reg = /(\d+\.\d+)/g;
string.match(reg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param $string
 * @return string
 * 
 * output
 * a.a.a.a.a.a.   => 0.0
 * 1.1.1.1.1.1.   => 1.11111
 * 2a$2.45&.wer.4 => 22.454 
 */
function stringToFlout($string) {
    $parts = explode('.', $string);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
        $parts[$i] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $parts[$i]);
    }

    $left = $parts[0];
    if (empty($left))
        $left = 0;

    $float[] = $left;

    unset($parts[0]);
    $right = implode('', $parts);
    if (empty($right))
        $right = 0;

    $float[] = $right;

    return implode('.', $float);
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. please add some explanation to your code - don't just answer with only code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```cpp
(0|([1-9][0-9]*))?\.(0|([1-9][0-9]*))
```

The `(0|([1-9][0-9]*))?` matches an optional integer part, the `\.` matches dot, and the final `(0|([1-9][0-9]*))` matches a mandatory fractional part.
It succeeds for:

- `.5`
- `0.5`
- `0.0`
- `0.1`
- `0.5foo`
- `31.41592`

It fails for:

- `00.5`
- `100`
- `nice`
- `2.`

Anchored version:

```cpp
^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))?\.(0|([1-9][0-9]*))$
```